# is Hausdorff distance a distance function on open convex sets?

Tags: metric-spaces, convex-geometry

I'm working with the set of all open convex bounded sets of $\ \mathbb{R}^n$ with the topology induced by the Hausdorff distance. Now this distance function is defined between two sets $\ X$ and $\ Y$ as follows:
$\ d_H(X,Y)=\max \{\sup_{x \in X}\ d(x,Y),\sup_{y \in Y}\ d(y,X) \}$, where $\ d(x,Y)=\inf_{y \in Y}\ d(x,y)$ and $\ d$ is the Euclidean distance.

I know that $\ d_H(X,Y)=0$ implies $\overline{X}=\overline{Y}$, but why does $\overline{X}=\overline{Y}$ imply $\ X=Y$ when both $\ X$ and $\ Y$ are open, convex and bounded? (Would be enough to show that bd$\ X=$ bd$\ Y$)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because $X=\textrm{int}{\overline{X}}$ for such sets. To see this, assume that $x\notin X$ is in the interior of the closure. Then some open subset of a small ball about $x$ is contained in $X$, and points on the opposite side of $x$ are in $X$ also, so $x\in X$ after all by convexity (picture works best perhaps).

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? If $x \in \mbox{int} \overline{X} - X$, then any open neighborhood of $x$ will intersect $X$, and the intersection is then an open set $U$, so for any $y \in U$, I can find an open ball around $y$ in $U \subseteq X$, but why should I have points on the opposite side of $x$ in $X$?

Comment: Because $X$ is dense in $\overline{X}$, so the points of $X$ are everywhere.

Comment: Great! I'm grateful for your help, now I see what's happening ...